# How to read this table/Json

Tags: jquery

I tried a lot to read this table but I couldn't, can someone help me? I need all the ids, i mean I need a loop that reads this table

```
[
    {"id":"871","name":"aaa"},
    {"id":"872","name":"a23"},
    {"id":"873","name":"qq"},

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$.getJSON("path/to/your/file.json", function(data) {
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i].id);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have an array of objects, so you want to loop through the array and then each array index has associative indexes of `id`/`name`.

I'll leave the exact implementation up to you.

BTW, the down-votes are because you aren't explaining any issue you ran into, it seems like you've not tried anything thus far...